# AWS CodeBuild user doesn't take on service role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am working on setting up a build project in CodeBuild that creates a Docker container from a GitHub repo, and pushes it to ECR. This build process uses a container built previously that's stored in ECR. That project runs fine.
The issue I am having, is despite the service role having AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser, the user CodeBuild uses is getting a permission denied on ecr:GetAuthorizationToken.
The user is called $ACCOUNT_NAME$-s3bucket. This is strange, as the project doesn't use S3 for anything during the build process. What is causing this issue?